# AdMob server registers ad requests, but Ad object contains 'must declare AdActivity' error

Tags: admob

I've been trying to implement the AdMob functionality into my project and have continued to hit a brick wall. I've been researching on the Web and taking note of the similar issues that fellow users are seeing, along with their solutions, but I seem to get so far and then can't *quite* get it to work. I'm hoping that someone will be able to point out some dumb error on my part!

Incidentally, I'm testing on a HTC Desire (Bravo) running Android 2.3.3 and using the latest AdMob SDK (4.3.1).

I can see from my AdMob account that the server is seeing Ad requests, but the Ad object in my application keeps stating that I need to declare AdActivity in my manifest, along with the configChange params. Both of which are there!

Any help would be much appreciated. Below are the associated (boiled-down) parts of my code;

**=================== AndroidManifest.xml =================================**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

package="<my package name>"

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:debuggable="false">

    <activity
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- AdMob stuff -->
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"/>           

    </application>
</manifest>
```

**====================== MainActivity.java =================================**

```
package my.package.name;

import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.choice_layout_main);   

    AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView); 
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest(); 
    adView.loadAd(adRequest); 


    }

}
```

**================ choice_layout_main.xml ==============================**

```
<ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"     
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@drawable/background_main"
      android:gravity="top"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
      android:scrollbars="vertical"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/MainLayout"  
        android:padding="50sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:backgroundColor="#000000"
        ads:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF"
        ads:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:refreshInterval="30"
        ads:adUnitId="<my id>"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        />   


      </RelativeLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

It seems that all other solutions shown by other developers don't quite work for me, so hence I think it must be some dumb point I'm overlooking!!

Any help would be good for my sanity!

Cheers,
Lee

Comment: Side note:  `ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"` and `AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest(); adView.loadAd(adRequest);` do the same thing.  You only need to do one of those!  What is happening now is the second request is being ignored because the first one is still being processed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using 4.3.1, your activity would probably need have some extra items under configChanges as below:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

Also, if you do this and you don't have the target set in your project.properties file (probably need to set `target=android-13` or higher assuming you have an Android SDK of 3.2 or higher).

Found this info in a blog post [here](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/11/migrating-to-v431-of-admob-sdk-for.html).